# How to add session to an HTML log in form

Tags: php, html, session

I'm working on an HTML form, which is connected to MySQL database. Database is updating with new data every time, when I reload the page and also when a failed submit occur. 
This is my code, Anyone please help me to add session to this page and please give me a solution

```
<body>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$email_id = $first_name = $last_name = $district = $city = $address = $mobile_no =            $password = "";
$email_idErr = $first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $districtErr = $cityErr = $addressErr =    $mobile_noErr = $passwordErr = "";
?>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
//First name validation
if(empty($_POST["first_name"]))
{$first_nameErr="First name is required";}
else
{$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
//checking name formats
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$first_name))
{$first_nameErr="Only letters and white spaces allowed";}
}
//Second name validation
if(empty($_POST["last_name"]))
{$last_nameErr="Last name is required";}
else
{$last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
//checking name formats 
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$last_name))
{$last_nameErr="Only letters and white spaces allowed";}
} 
//E-mail validation
if(empty($_POST["email_id"]))
{$email_idErr="E-mail id is required";}
else   
{$email_id = test_input($_POST["email_id"]);
//checking email format
if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email_id))
{$email_idErr="Invalid email format";}
}
//District is required
if(empty($_POST["district"]))
{ $districtErr="District is required";}
else
{ $district = test_input($_POST["district"]);
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$district))
{$districtErr="Only letters and white spaces allowed";}

}
$city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
$address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
//Mobile number validation  
if(empty($_POST["mobile_no"]))
{$mobile_noErr="Mobile number is required";}
else
{$mobile_no = test_input($_POST["mobile_no"]);
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$mobile_no))
{$mobile_noErr="Invalid Mobile number";}

}
//Password validation
if(empty($_POST["password"]))
{$passwordErr="Password is required";}
else
{ $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);

}
}
function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ashlyn");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {echo "Connection Established";}
$sql="INSERT INTO user_details (email_id, first_name, last_name, district, city,     address, mobile_no, password)
VALUES ('$email_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$district', '$city', '$address',  '$mobile_no', '$password')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "You are successfully registered..";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>User Login Page</h1>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);>"> 
        <p><input type="text" name="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name"><span  class="error">* <?php echo $first_nameErr;?></span></p>

         <p><input type="text" name="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $last_nameErr;?></span>
    </p>

         <p><input type="text" name="email_id" value="" placeholder="Email"><span class="error">* <?php echo $email_idErr;?></span>
    </p>

 <p><input type="text" name="district" value="" placeholder="District"><span class="error">* <?php echo $districtErr;?></span></p>

           <p><input type="text" name="city" value="" placeholder="City">
    </p>

            <p><input type="text" name="address" value="" placeholder="Address">
    </p>
                             <p><input type="text" name="mobile_no" value=""    placeholder="Mobile Number"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $mobile_noErr;?></span>
    </p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"> <span            class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
    </p>

    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>


      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is

```
<?php session_start();
```

on the first line bevor any output

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084900/1792420